# Finding product of a number without violating the threshold number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and trying to find the the value of `n` and `m` whose product would be closest to the number `max_available` without violating the threshold `threshold_number`. Currently I am using a while loop to find the value of `n` through division but if the value of `max_available` gets too big the number of while loop iterations would also increase which I want to avoid , following is the code I implemented.

```
n = 1
calculated_number =  max_available*max_multiple
while threshold_number < calculated_number:
    calculated_number = math.ceil((max_available/ n) * max_multiple)
    return_value = n
    n+=1
m = (max_available/ return_value )
```

Would there be a better way in python to avoid this while loop ? The product on n and m could be a bit higher than `max_available` but should be the closest

Comment: when you say multiple, do you mean product?

Comment: yes product would the correct word

Comment: I still don't really get the task. Do you want to find the biggest possible value of n? It's difficult for me to understand the role of each variable in your problem, specially __max_multiple__ and __max_available__

Comment: @Jalo max_multiple is just a constant , will always stay the same around the range of 4. max_available comes from some calculation. and yes you are right I need the maximum possible value of n which would not voilate our threshold

Comment: What if you just make  `calculated_number = threshold_number`, and get the max value of `n` from that. Afterwards you would just need to get the ceil of the obtained number. This way you don't need a loop